# Read data from API with Python encoded with base64 and gzip

Tags: php, python, gzip

I try to write my own API for our student timetable / schedule. There has been already a API written in PHP ([GitHub](https://github.com/irgendwr/dsbmobile-php-api/blob/master/dsb_api.php)), but I'd like to use Python.

Right now I am trying to read the data I get from the original API. This is the response:

```
{
  "d":
    "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"
}
```

In the PHP file it is decoded like this:

```
// parse json
$response = json_decode($response)->d;

// decode Base64
$response = base64_decode($response);

// decode gzip
$response = gzdecode($response);
```

I try to do the same with Python:

```
# Read JSON
data = r.json()["d"]

# Decode Base64
data_base64 = base64.b64decode(data)

# Decode GZIP
data_uncompressed = zlib.decompress(data_base64)

# Decode JSON
data_json = json.loads(data_uncompressed)
```

Unfortunately I get an error at decoding GZIP:

```
data_uncompressed = zlib.decompress(data_base64)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Does anyone know, what causes the error? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Wrong decompression. You want to use `gzip.decompress()` for full gzip data.